# Auto filled textbox using data from a table

Tags: javascript, html, sql, forms, textbox

I have a textbox for inputting the "milled volume" of a given log(wooden log). However I want to have this field auto filled by the same logs "initial volume" which is already filled and submitted in from a separate form and stored in a separate table, how can I reference the corresponding "initial volume" when a user clicks on the text box to fill in this text box

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Volume (m<sup>3</sup>)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="milled_volume" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you can do an SQL query(a function) where it selects the initial value and then put in into the input as `value="<?php getInitialValue();(the function for the SQL query) ?>"`. Of course, you will probably have different values right? Then store them into one table in MySQL and just print out the one you want, per say- you have a table with names for initial values and then just SELECT query it and print it out as starting value. Hope I understood your question and this helps you. Please post any questions you have, I may or may not understand the question :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Coja I'm not sure that would work, let me provide a few more details if that helps .. I use Postgres for anything SQL related and the volume figures are floats, I'm also trying as much as possible to avoid creating a brand new table just for this feature, hope that clears things up a bit thank you

Comment: Oh okay man, was just trying to help :) Sorry i wasn't able to answer your question